# How to switch case xsl:analyze-string instead of nesting?

Tags: xslt

In XSLT, we can use xsl:analyze-string to check input string with regex expression and get regex-group.

For example, I have following strings of shapes:

segment: 20m

triangle: 30m 30m 30m

rectangle: 10m 10m 30m 30m

...so on (but it is finite)

I want to use xml element to markup them with xsl:analyze-string.

Approach 1:

```
<xsl:for-each select="$lines">
    <xsl:analyze-string select="." regex="segment: (\w*)">
        <xsl:matching-substring>
            <segment seg1="{regex-group(1)}"/>
        </xsl:matching-substring>
    </xsl:analyze-string>

    <xsl:analyze-string select="." regex="triangle: (\w*), (\w*), (\w*)">
        <xsl:matching-substring>
            <triangle seg1="{regex-group(1)}" seg2="{regex-group(2)}" seg3="{regex-group(3)}"/>
        </xsl:matching-substring>
    </xsl:analyze-string>

    <xsl:analyze-string select="." regex="rectangle: (\w*), (\w*), (\w*), (\w*)">
        <xsl:matching-substring>
            <rectangle seg1="{regex-group(1)}" seg2="{regex-group(2)}" seg3="{regex-group(3)}" seg4="{regex-group(4)}"/>
        </xsl:matching-substring>
    </xsl:analyze-string>
 </xsl:for-each>
```

This approach has a disadvantage, that is: if we have some irregular data in line, it will ignore, but it should report error message.

Approach 2:

Nest xsl:analyze-string in xsl:non-matching-substring element, but there will be very ugly code if I have more than 8 kinds of Shape.

The best way to resolve this issue is integrating switch case or if else-if syntax in xsl:analyze-string.

So is there any way to switch case xsl:analyze-string in XSLT?

Comment: Is the task as regular as presented with the sample patterns (i.e. each shape name is associated with a number of  `\w*` sequences to form `segX` attributes)? In that case it should be possible to first match on the shape name and then process the data to create the attributes, as done in http://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/jyyiVhj.

Comment: @MartinHonnen Thank you for your solution, but there are some subtle differences between this solution and my example. In your case, it is assumed that the input can be written arbitrarily by the user (like the DSL code), so the number of consecutive spaces can be normalized. But in my case, the number of consecutive spaces is fixed, because the input is actually a log file that is automatically generated from a machine. I admit this example is not very good and I also had some misinterpretation of xsl: analyze-string earlier. (See my reply to Michael Kay)

Answer (score 0):

Use template matching.

In XSLT 3.0:

```
  <xsl:template match=".[starts-with(., 'segment)]">
    <xsl:analyze-string select="." regex="segment: (\w*)">
        <xsl:matching-substring>
            <segment seg1="{regex-group(1)}"/>
        </xsl:matching-substring>
    </xsl:analyze-string>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match=".[starts-with(., 'triangle)]">
    <xsl:analyze-string select="." regex="triangle: (\w*), (\w*), (\w*)">
        <xsl:matching-substring>
            <triangle seg1="{regex-group(1)}" seg2="{regex-group(2)}" seg3="{regex-group(3)}"/>
        </xsl:matching-substring>
    </xsl:analyze-string>
  </xsl:template>
```

etc.

and then

```
<xsl:apply-templates select="$lines"/>
```

Template rules that match atomic values are new in 3.0. In 2.0 you can use the same technique provided that the input ($lines) is a sequence of nodes, rather than a sequence of strings.

Comment: But this approach has some redundancy call. That is: starts-with(., 'segment) and regex="segment: (\w*)" are duplicated. Because If the conditions satisfy the regular expression, it must satisfy starts-with().

Comment: @chansey, the suggested approach does not really require you to spell out e.g. `regex="segment: ..."`, if you are concerned about that you can write a more generic pattern in front of the colon in the `regex` attribute value.

Comment: @chansey I've generally found it useful with this kind of application to separate (a) recognition of different kinds of record found in the input, and (b) processing of each kind of record. You could of course replace "segment" in the regex by something more generic, like [a-z]+, but I don't see the benefit in this case: the specific match makes the code more readable and will be faster.

Comment: I'm sorry, I found I had some misunderstandings about the semantics of xsl:analyze-string. xsl:analyze-string will find all substrings that match the regex (not just one!), the substrings that match the regex are processed within the <xsl:matching-substring> element. So xsl:analyze-string itself cannot implement the "switch case" syntax (this because XSLT instructions may run in parallel if do so will lead to inconsistencies). In this example, your approach is absolutely correct. Please forgive me.

Comment: But this is not enough, what I really want is to be able to get group info while matching regular expressions. For example, fn:matches() in XPath, it can determine whether it matched or not, but it never tells me the matching information at the same time. In C#, we can call regex.Match(), it returns Match object which contains the matching information (eg: group information), if unmatch, then the value of Match object is EmptyString. We can use this value to if or switch case syntax to check it and get this information to further process.

Comment: @chansey, in XSLT/XPath 3 you have an `analyze-string` function https://www.w3.org/TR/xpath-functions/#func-analyze-string in addition to the `xsl:analyze-string` instruction, it returns an XML structure with information like matches and groups, so that comes close (albeit in a completely different format) to what the .NET framework returns with the `Match` method.

Comment: @MartinHonnen Good answer, this is really what I want. I wrote a solution for this question by using this new XPath function. see http://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/pPgCcoo/5  But unfortunately, this code only work in xsltfiddle, but not in Oxygen XML Editor. In Oxygen XML Editor, it report error: Engine name: Saxon-EE 9.7.0.15 Severity: error Description: Internal error evaluating template rule  at line 10

Comment: @MartinHonnen It also can work in Saxon-PE/HE 9.7.0.15, but cant work in EE.

Comment: @chansey, in general, if you have problems with Saxon inside oXygen, then first try whether there is an update for oXygen and/or its Saxon plugin available, then, if the problem persists, ask in the oXygen forum on their website whether the problem is related to oXygen or Saxon. The latest releases of the open-source Saxon HE 9.7 or 9.8 are also available on SourceForge https://sourceforge.net/projects/saxon/files/Saxon-HE/, so you could use them independent of oXygen to test whether the problem is related to oXygen or Saxon.

Comment: @MartinHonnen, Using XPath 3's new function analyze-string can do what I want, but code still be tediously long. For example: <triangle seg1="{$match-triangle/fn:match/fn:group[1]}" .../>, is there any way to omit the namespace 'fn'?

Comment: In XSLT 2 or 3 you can always define `xpath-default-namespace="http://www.w3.org/2005/xpath-functions"`, for instance if you put that on your `xsl:choose` then inside with all XPath expressions you don't need the prefix to select the elements returned by the `analyze-string` function in the function namespace.